# Breaking out of .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to break out of `.each()` iterations and it doesn't allow me to. Here is my code. Thanks for the help guys! Appreciate it.

```
$('#btn-submit-add').click(function(){
    var answerField = 1;
    $('.addAnswerChoice').each(function(){
        var answerChoice = $(this).val();
        if (answerChoice == ""){
            $('#answerChoice-'+answerField+'-Error').show();
            $(this).focus();
            return false; // this doesn't work
        }
        answerField++;
    });
    alert('doing stuff after');
});
```

Comment: verify that `if (answerChoice == "")` is working or not? You can use `alert("message")` or `console.log("message")` to test

Comment: Are those checkboxes you are checking?

Comment: @Tarek not the same... Tarok Kins, html please

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jfWeN/2/

Comment: @SalmanA text inputs with class .addAnswerChoice

Comment: @TarokKins check the above fiddle.. does it work for you

Comment: @Bilal It does check if its empty or not. I want it to stop if its empty. Working fine in jsFiddle as per Arun but its not on my end.

Comment: @TarokKins jquery version used

Comment: @TarokKins any error in your console

Comment: Are you trying to return `false` from the `.click()` handler?

Comment: @TarokKins better you upload your code on jsfiddle or jsbin, it will help us to understand the problem

Comment: Did you get in `if` statement? You can try to use `if (!answerChoice)` or `if (answerChoice === "")`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes. There can/may be several .addAnswerChoice text elements at a time upon click. Once iteration checks empty answerChoice, shows the error element and should stop. In this case it doesn't and shows the alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to return `false` from the click handler to cancel the submit. The way you have it your `return false` statement returns from the function you passed to `.each()`, which does break out of the `.each()` loop but it doesn't return from the outer function that is the click handler. So execution then continues with the statement after the `.each()`, i.e., the final alert. And your click is not cancelled. Try this instead:

```
$('#btn-submit-add').click(function(e){
    var answerField = 1;
    $('.addAnswerChoice').each(function(){
        var answerChoice = $(this).val();
        if (answerChoice == ""){
            $('#answerChoice-'+answerField+'-Error').show();
            $(this).focus();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        answerField++;
    });
});
```

jQuery passes the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to your click handler (notice I've added a parameter called `e`), so you can use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop the click from working.

Comment: Good explanation as well! Ill stick this to my head.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is almost like `each` only but short-circuits when the first `true` value is returned. So, you don't have to explicitly break out of the iterations.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("addAnswerChoice")).some(function(item) {
 var answerChoice = item.value;
 if (answerChoice == ""){     
        $('#answerChoice-'+answerField+'-Error').show();
        item.focus();
        return true;
 }
 return false;
});
```

Comment: @nnnnnn Just updated my solution. Please check now :)

Comment: OK. But this is now essentially the non-jQuery version of the OP's code, so I don't see that it makes much difference. I think the OP's real problem is how to return false from the click handler...

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh... But I read just the question and he didnt mention that in the question, I believe.

Comment: I know OP didn't mention it - that's just my guess based on the id of the element the click is bound to and the fact that the code seems to be validating fields to ensure they're not empty...

Comment: @nnnnnn Oops... I really thought he doesn't know to break out of `each`. Thats why I was suggesting this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

---

Edit:

if @nnnnnn is right, the code should look like:

```
$('#btn-submit-add').click(function(){
    var validated = true;
    var answerField = 1;
    $('.addAnswerChoice').each(function(){
        var answerChoice = $(this).val();
        if (answerChoice == ""){
            $('#answerChoice-'+answerField+'-Error').show();
            $(this).focus();
            validated = false;
            return false;
        }
        answerField++;
    });
    if (!validated)
    {
        return false;
    }
    alert('doing stuff after');
});
```

Comment: @nnnnnn: so the OP's problem is elsewhere and the topic of this question is wrong. Probably his `answerChoice` is not empty at all but it contains some whitespaces for example

Comment: My guess is that OP wants to return `false` from the click handler to cancel the submit.

Comment: @Adassko checking empty elements and its working and showing the error element and focus.